# Conditional if statement ($post->ID == get_the_ID) not working

Tags: bbpress

The following code should read: If the current custom post type (bbp_forum), is the one being displayed, assign the **class** 'current' to its respective `<li>` tag. But for some reason the class **'current'** (to highlight the current `bbp_forum` link) is being displayed in all the `<li>` tags:

[image]

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="masthead">
            <div id="branding" role="banner">
                <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            </div><!-- #branding -->
            <div id="access" role="navigation">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- #access -->
        </div><!-- #masthead -->
        <ul id="forums">
          <?php global $post; $cat_posts = get_posts('post_type=bbp_forum');
          foreach($cat_posts as $post) : ?>
            <li <?php if($post->ID == get_the_ID()){ ?>class="current" <?php } ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
             </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul><!-- #access -->
    </div><!-- #header -->

    <div id="main">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression will always be true. Take a look at `get_the_ID()`;

```
function get_the_ID() {
    global $post;
    return $post->ID;
}
```

So your code is effectively running as;

```
if ( $post->ID == $post->ID ) // always true!
```

Instead, cache the ID of the main post in a variable, then compare that instead.

```
<?php

global $post;

/**
 * @var int Current post ID.
 */
$the_post_ID = $post->ID;

/**
 * @var array All posts for bbp_forum.
 */
$cat_posts = get_posts('post_type=bbp_forum');

?>

<?php foreach ( $cat_posts as $post ) : ?>

    <li<?php if ( $post->ID == $the_post_ID ) echo ' class="current"'; ?>>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```